# HTML5 Player is slow on some Devices?

Tags: html, video, flv, mp4

I've recently switched my clients site from an FLV video site to an HTML5 MP4 site.

In doing this they had a limited size server so we couldn't do flash fallbacks...

Yet we have the site running well on iOS devices and most laptops but he tells me sometimes that the videos take verrrry long to load on their Macbook... I assume they're on Safari which I am myself using and it works fine.

But what could cause differences in playback start times? I know internet speed does but they tell me they done it on an ipad then straight after did it on a macbook and the macbook failed to load the buffering video in an acceptable time.

- Could it be:
- Browser versions?
- Server Configuration?
- Operating System?

Im stumped! But either way, they all work sweet on my iMac, iPhone, Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Could it possibly be the way the MP4s have been encoded? If the video index is at the end of the file then the browser has to load the entire thing before it can play it.

I wrote about it [How to get your HTML5 MP4 video file to play before being fully downloaded](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/03/html5/how-to-get-your-html5-mp4-video-file-to-play-before-being-fully-downloaded) and how you can fix it.

I know that it may not fix the problem per say, but it just strikes a chord that it might be related.

Comment: Also, out of interest, why can't you also provide a Flash fallback that plays the MP4 file, since you're already using them for HTML5? The Longtail HTML5 player download inclides a Flash player (player.swf) which you can use to playback MP4 files.

Comment: Was pulling my hair out trying to fix Safari having a delay in loading  some streaming mp4s. The QTIndexswapper fixed it, thank you very Ian!

Comment: If you implement HTML5 video streaming protocol then the whole file will not be loaded. The browser will request for a smaller chunk from the end of the file and then start streaming from the start. However you may also transfer the index from end of video to the begining using the following FFMPEG command: "ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v copy -movflags faststart output.mp4" use it without quotes.